# Reset Apple Mail auto suggest?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

Using Apple Mail to handle my email there is a great feature that when you select an email to move to a folder it suggests one, presumably based on a previous move. Is there a way to 'reset' this? At the moment it appears to want to move to the older folder but now I want to use a new one. I have moved dozens of emails to the new location but it doesn't appear to have learned this.

I'm guessing there must be a file in the Application support directory that keeps a record of all of this but any idea which one?

I'm running Mojave 10.14.2

Thanks